# Best way to handle 10k dictionary I want to be able to refer to?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary file that's about 10k lines.  It stores a bunch of information that I want to be able to grab and refer to from time to time in my app.  What is the best way to include this data in my app?

I tried making a .swift file where I just say:

```
let magicDict = [_10k lines of dictionary values_]
```

But that feels like the wrong way and it's slowed my build times to a crawl.  (Is that because xcode is pulling that file into every one of my files?)

Should this be a model?  Something else?  It's just a bunch of static data.

Comment: Create a plist or csv file which is loaded as a dictionary at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As JAL says, read it from a file. Plists are perfect for this purpose. Take a look at the `NSDictionary` methods `NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:)` and `NSDictionary(contentsOf:)`. One takes a path, the other an URL.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a static plist, json, xml or any other format that you feel comfortable with, and read it during runtime into a dictionary.